# Silverstripe 4 show specific records in GridField

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I created a module that will allow certain user groups to create a request in the CMS.Any logged in user can access the module.
When user visit 'RequestModeule' in in CMS section in GRID CMS FIELDS I want to show him the requests he only sent not another customer requests. The system displays the requirements of all users and he see all.

How do I set the CMS FIELDS results to be displayed for the currently logged in user.

*This is a ecommerce site and some customers want to return the product, some want to replace the product, some want to complain about the quality. I want to allow customers to submit a request themselves. I started with a simple model, so I will expand it when I solve big problems.*

**Here is my Model.**

```
class Request extends DataObject
{
    private static $db = [
        'FullName' => 'Varchar',
        'RequestText' => 'Text'
    ];


    private static $has_one = [
        'Photo' => Image::class
    ];


    public function canView($member = null)
    {
        return Permission::check('VIEW_REQUEST', 'any', $member);
    }

    public function canEdit($member = null)
    {
        return Permission::check('EDIT_REQUEST', 'any', $member);
    }

    public function canDelete($member = null)
    {
        return Permission::check('DELETE_REQUEST', 'any', $member);
    }

    public function canCreate($member = null, $context = [])
    {
        return Permission::check('CREATE_REQUEST', 'any', $member);
    }

    /**
     * @return \SilverStripe\Forms\FieldList
     */
    public function getCMSFields()
    {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', TextField::create('FullName'));
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', TextField::create('RequestText'));
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Photos', $img = UploadField::create('Photo', 'Main photo'));

        $img->setFolderName("products");
        $img->setAllowedExtensions(["png", "jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "webp"]);
        
        return $fields;
    }
}
```

**Request Controller**

```
class Request_Controller extends ContentController implements PermissionProvider
{

    function providePermissions(){
        return array(
            "CREATE_REQUEST" => "Create REQUEST",
            "EDIT_REQUEST" => "Edit REQUEST",
            "VIEW_REQUEST" => "View REQUEST",
            "DELTE_REQUEST" => "Delete REQUEST",
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't see anything about connecting your `Request` class with a `Member`. If you want to only show the things a member has created, you need to somehow store the Members ID or something.

The most obvious way to do this would be a `private static $has_one = ['CreatedBy' => Member::class]`.

(and during creation you'll have to put the member ID into CreatedBy. For example you can do `protected function onBeforeWrite() { parent::onBeforeWrite(); $this->CreatedByID = Security::getCurrentUser()->ID; }`)

---

As for the GridField:

There are 2 ways to control what is displayed in a GridField:

1. `GridField`s 3rd argument is any `SS_List` instance, so you can filter or customize that any way you want. For example you can use `Request::get()->filter('CreatedByID' => 13)` to only show the objects created by member ID 13.
2. You can use `canView` on each `Request` object. If it returns false, it will not be shown. So you can do `public function canView($member = null) { return $member && $member->ID === $this->CreatedByID && Permission::check('VIEW_REQUEST', 'any', $member); }`